# How many US states receive large amounts of money due to SLS?

Tags: nasa, cost, sls, united-states, government

That NASA is spread out over so many locations across the US is history and discussed elsewhere in this site. Briefly, Congress approves funding and the funding ends up in many, many of congress' districts and states.

I'd like to ask if the [SLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Launch_System) funding is anywhere near as widely dispersed over many states as NASA's overall budget, or if it ends up mostly in only one or two states.

The motivation of this question is in no way related to [Why does the government still fund SLS while SpaceX is cheaper and has the same capabilities if not better?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45420/12102)

Comment: Seeing that the same people that developed the way overspent F35 are developing SLS I am willing to bet that they have tried to penetrate most states to ensure funding. Trying to find the articles saying this as they usually boast about it.

Comment: I can't see it bad - if socialist style state politics causes Space Exploration, then this time do the politicians some useful. This money could have spent also to build state parks and PR buildings.

Comment: None. NASA doesn't have a big budget, so can't spend a large amount of money anywhere.

The annual budget for SLS is around 2.5 billion dollars, around a hundredth of a percent of the US GDP.

Comment: While it can't provide a good answer in regards to funding amounts, I think the following website does a good job of showing the spread of contractors for Deep Space Exploration Systems, which SLS is included in. Every state has a a contractor in it and many states have over 50. https://www.nasa.gov/specials/ESDSuppliersMap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SLS major work locations:

- Alabama- Testing & upper stage, engineering design
- Mississippi- Testing
- Utah- Solid rocket motor
- Florida- Launch pad updates
- Louisiana- Core booster, Orion
- California- Main engines
- Colorado- Engineering for upper stage, Orion

So far as I can tell, it seems like these are where the major contracts are, although I don't doubt that most states have a large piece. Not a crazy amount of states, but still a pretty good collection.